# Can WP ecommerce collect card info without charging?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm new to ecommerce but have some experience with Wordpress. My client is wanting to have the customer put their card information in but not charge them. They are wanting to do it manually. Is WP ecommerce okay for this? If not, what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

credit card info is not stored anywhere, it's transmitted securely to the payment processor and then forgotten. storing cc info introduces a host of potential security issues and requires you be [PCI compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) for storing sensitive info.